# how to pass utf-8 data from Django to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, python-2.7

I have the following key value object in Django:

```
data = {
    "id": 1,
    "question_text": "אנא בחר אחת מהתשובות הבאות",
    "answers": [
     {
        "label" : "תשובה 1",
        "value" : 1,
        "count" : 30
     },
     {
        "label" : "תשובה 2",
        "value" : 2,
        "count" : 30
     },
     {
        "label" : "תשובה 3",
        "value" : 3,
        "count" : 30
     },
}
```

Note that some of the data is in Hebrew so when I save it in to the DB I use:

```
unicode(self.answer_text).encode('utf-8')
```

When I tried to send this object to a view, in order to use it in a Django template and as well in Javascript

I have used this line:

```
return render(request, 'reports/report.html', {'data': data })
```

and in the view I used:

```
var question_data = {{ data }} #in order to get the data object that was sent to the view
```

But I get this element:

```
{&#39;bad&#39;: 45, &#39;good&#39;: 55, &#39;question_text&#39;: u&#39;\u05e2\u05d3 \u05db\u05de\u05d4 \u05d0\u05ea\u05d4 \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4 \u05d0\u05d5 \u05dc\u05d0 \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4 \u05de\u05d1\u05d2\u05d3\u05d9 \u05e2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea \u05d1\u05d0\u05d5\u05e4\u05df \u05db\u05dc\u05dc\u05d9?&#39;, &#39;id&#39;: u&#39;8&#39;, &#39;answers&#39;: [{&#39;value&#39;: 30, &#39;label&#39;: u&#39;\u05de\u05d0\u05d5\u05d3 \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: 25, &#39;label&#39;: u&#39;\u05d3\u05d9 \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: 20, &#39;label&#39;: u&#39;\u05dc\u05d0 \u05db\u05dc \u05db\u05da \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: 25, &#39;label&#39;: u&#39;\u05db\u05dc\u05dc \u05dc\u05d0 \u05de\u05e8\u05d5\u05e6\u05d4&#39;}]}
```

and this error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name
```

I have also tried to use:

```
var question_data = {{ data|safe }}
```

and I got this error:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal '\u05e2\u05d3 ...
```

I'm using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7.6

Please try and help me understand what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**View**

```
import json
# ....
return render(request, 'reports/report.html', {'data': json.dumps(data) })
```

**Template**

```
<script>
  var question_data = JSON.parse("{{ data|escapejs }}");
  console.log(question_data);
</script>
```

Also, you might have a syntax error in your python dict (missing closing bracket).

**EDIT**

```
return render(request, 'reports/report.html', {'data': data, 'data_json': json.dumps(data) })
```

Comment: But now when I tried to use `{{ data.question_text }}` I get an empty string, I would like to use this code instead of using Javascript for that

Comment: You can't access json members in your template. Just add to your context another set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

For show JSON fron Views Django, you must escape data with filter:

```
var categories = JSON.parse("{{ categories|escapejs }}");
```